# POSIX compatible TAR for AIX and Solaris

Tags: tar, solaris, aix

I have created a TAR archive with our product using maven-assembly-plugin. The TAR archive is in the POSIX format. Our QA complains about `PaxHeaders.X` files when extracted.

Do the AIX (version AIX 7.1 TL5) and Solaris (version 10) vendors provide POSIX compatible TAR at all or are they relying only on 3rd party TAR implementations like BSD tar and GNU tar?

I don't want to fall back to ustar format unless I absolutely have to. I hope I don't have to.

### UPDATE 1

I found that IBM offers RPMs for various GNU packages, including TAR, at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/883796

### UPDATE 2

The issue is that the tools our QA used are extracting the POSIX format tar with truncated file names. The `PaxHeaders.X` files are a side effect of how the POSIX tar format is structured and how it is interpreted by the old TARs.

Comment: `pax` is the POSIX command to extract `tar` archives. `tar` is not a POSIX command.

Comment: AFAIK, both AIX 7.1 and Solaris 10 are EOL

Comment: Ah sorry, looks like Solaris 10 is not longer eol as they've extended support to Jan 2025.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you. I tested it but it does not seem to work any better than stock AIX tar.

Comment: It would help to see the exact error, the exact command you ran and a sample tar file that exhibits the problem.

Comment: It's unclear whether the "update 1" addition to the question means the issue has gone away.

Comment: @Kusalananda It partially solves the issue only because it helps only on AIX.

Comment: You have it backwards.  It's usually GNU `tar` that fails to produce standards-compliant archives.  If the Solaris `tar` command can't handle the tar archive, the tar archive you are producing is probably *not* a POSIX-compliant archive.  If the Solaris `pax` command can't handle the tar archive, it is certainly not a POSIX-compliant archive. **Beware** GNU `tar` - GNU effectively embraced, extended, and extinguished `tar` as a standard. That's *why* `tar` is no longer a POSIX standard. GNU *broke* it with "good ideas". The late Jörg Schilling could (and would...) expound for hours about that.

Comment: @OP So your tar-files are actually pax-files. Maybe you can find an option to generate real tar-files instead. (I.e. tar without pax-extensions.)

Comment: TL:DR pax-file format is not _"the official"_ standard, it is the _"used rarely if ever"_ standard.